# How to genearte the random number in increasing order

Tags: java

I would like to generate random numbers in ascending order, for instance: `0, 2, 3, 5 .. 100`, but not `2, 0, 5 ..`

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public static int vol=5;    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int randno = getRandNum();
    vol = vol+randno;   
    System.out.println(getRandNum());
}   
private static  int getRandNum() {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int v=r.nextInt(vol);
        System.out.println("r"+v);
    }
    return vol;
}
```

How could I achieve the goal stated above?

Comment: Create them then sort them in increasing order.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I would give a suggestion which might be easier to go with your current implementation. Don't bother about the order now. Populate them in an array or list and sort them. This would be far better and easier to do.

Comment: why you are calling getRandNum() 2 times

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Generates random numbers, returning an array of ascending order.
 * @param amount    The amount of numbers to generate.
 * @param max       The maximum value to generate.
 * @return  An array of random integers of the specified length.
 */
public static int[] generateIncreasingRandoms(int amount, int max) {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[amount];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = random.nextInt(max);
    }
    Arrays.sort(randomNumbers);
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

You could use it like so:

```
// Generates 10 random numbers of value 0 to 100,
// printing them in ascending order
for (int number : generateIncreasingRandoms(10, 100)) {
    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

---

Or if you're a micro-optimization kind of person and do not wish to sort,

```
/**
 * Generates random numbers, returning an array of ascending order.
 * @param amount    The amount of numbers to generate.
 * @param max       The maximum value to generate.
 * @return  An array of random integers of the specified length.
 */
public static int[] generateIncreasingRandomWithoutSorting(int amount, int max) {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[amount];
    double delta = max / (float)amount;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = (int)Math.round(i*delta + random.nextDouble() * delta);
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

Use case:

```
// Generates 10 random numbers of value 0 to 100,
// printing them in ascending order
for (int number : generateIncreasingRandomWithoutSorting(10, 100)) {
    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

The reason that each number is between 0-10, 10-20, 20-30.. in this use case is that if I simply allow for the entire range and you get a 100 on the first try you're going to end up with an entire array of 100s.

Being more controlled, with this solution you are not really getting what you're asking for ("10 numbers of 0 to 100 sorted ascendingly") since it modifies the range for each consecutive number. (like any other solution that doesn't require sorting)

Answer (score 2):

Ben Barkay's answer is good, but if you don't want to create a set of numbers in one step, but you want to get one number after another, you can do something like this:

```
private static final int MAX = 5;

private Random rand = new Random();
private int maxRand = 0;

public int getIncreasingRandomNumber() {
    maxRand = rand.nextInt(MAX);
    return maxRand;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
public class increasing {
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Random r = new Random(); 

        int totalNums = 100; 
        int count = 0;

        int lastVal = 0;
        int currVal = 0;
        while(count < totalNums) { 
            currVal = r.nextInt(200);
            lastVal = lastVal + currVal; 
            System.out.println(lastVal + ",");
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, I came here just to write a similar solution. No need to sort, just add some more random and sum up with the last one. Brilliant!

Comment: This does not have a uniform random distribution, though.

Comment: I believe if two numbers `x1` and `x2` are generated randomly then there sum `x1 + x2` is sufficiently random. Do you disagree with that? On uniform random distribution - don't forget that we are talking about a set of numbers which are strictly ascending so ofcourse we cannot have uniform distribution. Please correct me if I am mistaken.