# Random number generator that returns unique entries in sorted order

Tags: java, algorithm, random, sequence, distribution

I need a generator for many (up to one trillion, 10^12) unique random 64-bit numbers.
The generator needs to return the numbers in sorted order (Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE). The problem is that sorting $10^{12}$ numbers is slow. The use case is replicating a test that was run for [BBHash](https://github.com/rizkg/BBHash) (in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03154.pdf), 4.5 Indexing a trillion keys).

The straightforward solution is to create a set in memory, using a huge bit set or so
to ensure no duplicates are returned.
But that uses too much memory or I/O.
I'd like to use at most a few MB of internal state.

The generator should use a java.util.Random internally.
It should be as "fair" as possible (have the same statistical distribution as if generated otherwise). I would also like to have a version for 128-bit numbers (2 longs).

What I have so far is code to create a set in memory (Java code):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for(long x : randomSet(10, 0)) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

static Iterable<Long> randomSet(int size, int seed) {
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    TreeSet<Long> set = new TreeSet<Long>();
    while (set.size() < size) {
        set.add(r.nextLong());
    }
    return set;
}

-8292973307042192125
-7423979211207825555
-6688467811848818630
-4962768465676381896
-2228689144322150137
-1083761183081836303
-279624296851435688
4437113781045784766
6146794652083548235
7105486291024734541
```

The simplest (wrong) solution, which is not random, is to distribute the results evenly.
I don't think a solution along the line of "add a random gap" will work,
because it is slow, and the sum of such gaps, after 10^12, will not land where it should (well, maybe: remember how many numbers are left, then re-calculate the distribution...). I think the following should work, but is complex, and not sure what formulas to use: for each bit level,
recursively, calculating how many 0s / 1s will likely occur
(using the Binomial distribution or the approximation, the normal / Gaussian distribution, somehow).
Stop at some point (say, blocks of 1 million entries or less),
use the code above, for speed.
But maybe there is an elegant solution.
Maybe this is related to the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm, not sure.
I read "An Efficient Algorithm for Sequential Random Sampling",
but I think it is only for small n, and I find it hard to get to a simple algorithm from this.

Java code would be best, but C is fine (anyway at some point I might have to convert it to C / C++). I would like to not use too many libraries, to simplify porting.

Comment: I don't see why the random gap approach wouldn't work. One trillion numbers distributed over the interval from -2^63 to 2^63 - 1 gives an average gap of 18,446,744. If you generate gaps in the range from say, half a million to 36 and a half million, evenly distributed (or Gaussian distributed), they will tend to the right size over time. The generator would use very little memory. But I suppose it all depends on what you want to use the numbers for.

Comment: @DavidConrad I think the probability distribution would be "wrong" (statistically not match the real world) with Gaussian or even distribution. I think gaps should use Poisson distribution (not completely sure). But if that is used, generating would be relatively slow. I would prefer a solution where I can say "this many numbers are in this range", and then fill that range using a faster method (like the brute force one in the question).

Comment: You can't know what the distribution of the first value should be, unless you know exactly how many values you will generate in total. Intuitively, the more numbers you will generate, the smaller the expected value of the first value. So is it "up to one trillion" or some specific number of values you'll generate?

Comment: Randomly decide how many neg and pos numbers; then for each of those, randomly decide how many numbers in first half and second half of that range, and so on... like  building a binary tree where each node is distributed randomly over its children? Not sure which distribution to use though... Decisions higher up have more impact.

Comment: @m69 yes, so far I think that's a good solution. I'm struggling to find what formula to use. I think it's the Binominal distribution, which can be approximated using the Normal / Gaussian distribution. But then I'm stuck, I think you need to use cumulative distribution. Another solution might be, what is the range for the next 1 million random numbers, but for that I don't know what distribution to use.

Comment: Just to be clear: the "too much memory" in this case would be 8 TB. You do need to take a compromise here, and do not considered the "storing the set" scenario a valid option.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19971987/2579220

Comment: @ThomasMueller I guess that's what stats.stackexchange.com is for :-)

Comment: @m69 Hm, I think you are right... But it's more likely to get an efficient algorithm here, or a non-obvious solution.

Comment: Just tell them you want to use the binary tree-like algorithm, but don't know how to bias the random decision at each level.

Comment: @m69 Asked a question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289300/random-number-generator-that-returns-unique-entries-in-sorted-order)

Comment: When you say you need up to a trillion values, I'm assuming that you're specifying how many you need as an input so as to address the issue raised by @BeeOnRope.  Does it have to be the exact number you specify, or can the quantity vary by a small amount?

Comment: Hm, not really a friendly bunch over on Cross Validated; it's like posting a question with the [c++] tag here :-) If only someone could confirm the suggestion in your last paragraph about coin flips and normal distribution, you'd have a relatively easy to program solution that could be fast too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution.

(It turns out, generating 100'000 or more entries in *roughly* sorted order is faster than generating using a large HashSet. Roughly sorted means replace `TreeSet` with a `HashSet`, and using a limit of 10'000 instead of 5. This is because testing for duplicates is much faster.)

#### Random number of entries for each fixed (sub-)range

Create a tree: For each bit level (starting with the most significant bit), recursively generate a random number of how many entries should have the bit at that level set to 0, using the normal distribution. The remaining entries have the bit at this level set to 1. At each recursion level, this will narrow the range by about half. Stop for example when there are less than 1 million entries, and then switch to using an in-memory pseudo-RNG and sort those numbers (or use a bit field).

Here some code (not tested yet):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Iterator<Long> it = randomSequence(r, 10, 32);
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}

/**
 * Random sequence generator.
 *
 * @param r the random generator
 * @param size the number of entries to generate
 * @param shift the number of bits of the result
 * @return the iterator
 */
static Iterator<Long> randomSequence(final Random r, final long size, final int shift) {
    if (size < 5) {
        // small lists are generated using a regular hash set
        TreeSet<Long> set = new TreeSet<Long>();
        while (set.size() < size) {
            set.add(r.nextLong() & ((2L << shift) - 1));
        }
        return set.iterator();
    }
    // large lists are created recursively
    return new Iterator<Long>() {
        long remaining = size, zeros = randomHalf(r, size);
        Iterator<Long> lowBits0 = randomSequence(r, zeros, shift - 1);
        Iterator<Long> lowBits1;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return remaining > 0;
        }
        @Override
        public Long next() {
            remaining--;
            if (lowBits0.hasNext()) {
                return lowBits0.next();
            }
            if (lowBits1 == null) {
                lowBits1 = randomSequence(r, size - zeros, shift - 1);
            }
            return (1L << shift) + lowBits1.next();
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Get the number of entries that are supposed to be below the half,
 * according to the probability theory. For example, for a number of coin
 * flips, how many are heads.
 *
 * @param r the random generator
 * @param samples the total number of entries
 * @return the number of entries that should be used for one half
 */
static long randomHalf(Random r, long samples) {
    long low = 0, high = samples;
    double x = r.nextDouble();
    while (low + 1 < high) {
        long mid = (low + high) / 2;
        double p = probabilityBucketAtMost(samples, mid);
        if (x > p) {
            low = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    return (low + high) / 2;
}

static double probabilityBucketAtMost(long flips, long heads) {
    // https://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/statistics.html
    long x = heads;
    long n = flips;
    double variance = Math.sqrt(n/4);
    // mean
    long mu = n / 2;
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
    // Numerical approximations for the normal CDF
    // the probability that the value of a standard normal random variable X is <= x
    return phi((x - mu) / variance);
}

static double phi(double x) {
    return 0.5 * (1 + Math.signum(x) * Math.sqrt(1 - Math.exp(-2 * x * x / Math.PI)));
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you got it to work; were the answers on  stats.SE of any help ?

Comment: Not really, this is based on what I found myself. Now need to test if the distribution matches a regular random number generator.

Comment: And, what properties in particular of the sequence do you intend to verify? (These would be helpful in the first place to come up with a fitting algorithm)

Comment: @mvw I will try to verify the average gap, high bits, low bits, and so on matches a regular random number generator. Maybe using the [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).

Answer (score 1):

For the requirements

> 1. generate a sequence of random numbers r_i from a whole number interval I = [-(R+1), R], R > 0 with a statistical distribution like
>      java.util.Random
> 2. the sequence r_i must be strictly increasing (r_i > r_j for i > j)

we could come up with a simple algorithm

```
A1:
 - draw a random number r_i from I via a library call
 - discard it, if it is less or equal the last draw, try another pick
```

The possible complaint would be that this algorithm would probably give not the right number of generated r_i, there is a fuzzy requirement about N=10^12 expected numbers in total

> 3. "need a generator for many (up to one trillion, 10^12) unique random 64-bit numbers"

The solution for this would be

```
A2:
 - to generate N numbers and then 
 - sort them
```

However there is another requirement, that there is not enough memory available.

> 4. "I'd like to use at most a few MB of internal state."

My conjecture is that it is not possible to fulfill all these requirements at once.

As a compromise I suggest

```
A3:
 R=2^63 = 9 10^18  
 N=1 Trillion = 10^12
 - divide the range I=[-R,R-1] into N intervals of length (2R+1)/N each 
 - visit each of those intervals (visiting one interval after another)
 - draw a random number from that interval
```

This will give N random numbers, in increasing order.

**Update:**

After skimming the [BBHash paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03154) and [sources](https://github.com/rizkg/BBHash) a couple of times this is my understanding:

Given some integer set I and a subset S with N=|S| elements, the BBHash procedure will calculate a function f which maps S to some permutation of {1,..,N} (what permutation seems to be implicitly decided by the BBHash procedure) and maps all other elements from I to a special value Imax from I.

Possible tests:

Given S and f one might check if membership in S for some arbitrary element from I is properly calculated.

One might also check if f(S) = {1,..,N}.

My guess is that the requested algorithm is intended to calculate a sample set S for N=10^12 on the fly under tight memory budget, needing uniqueness of the random number sequence rather than monotony.

To quote https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050835/2579220

> Probabilistic data structures can't give you a definite answer,
>   instead they provide you with a reasonable approximation of the answer
>   and a way to approximate this estimation. They are extremely useful
>   for big data and streaming application because they allow to
>   dramatically decrease the amount of memory needed (in comparison to
>   data structures that give you exact answers).
>
> In majority of the cases these data structures use hash functions to
>   randomize the items. Because they ignore collisions they keep the size
>   constant, but this is also a reason why they can't give you exact
>   values.

In case of BBHash a sequence of different hash functions h_i is used. One applies different h_i until no collision occurs. This only works if the input is unique. It will only work if the implementation has enough different h_i in store for the particular S.

Comment: Divide into N evenly spaced intervals? That would mean, there are exactly half the values below 0, and half above zero. That is not random.

Comment: I provided the source code. If you run it, you will see many negative values (more than positive, with this seed). I wrote that distributing the results evenly is not random.

Comment: If you run your algorithm, the result is always: half the number below zero, half above zero. That is not random. Always exactly one entry for each range, that is not random. In reality, sometimes there are more, and sometimes less entries in one interval.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your universe of random values U. For starters, that's the range of 64-bit signed integers, so has 2 ^ 64 possible values. Let's call the total number of sorted random values you need to produce N, which you say is about a 10 ^ 12.

Decide up front how much is a reasonable amount of memory to use. Let's say your machine can allocate and use 1GB with no problems. That's 134,217,728 64-bit values. Call that A (array size).

N / A = 7450.58..., so round up to 7451 buckets, and adjust A to ceil(N/7451), which is 134,210,173. Calculate R (bucket range) = U/7451.

```
Loop over 7451 buckets (B):
    Generate 134,210,173 random values in the range (0..R),
    inserting them into the array as they are produced. Binary
    insertion should be reasonable (N*log(N), just like generating
    them all then sorting, but you can use the insertion to catch
    duplicates so you don't need extra memory or time for that).

    Output the bucket of values, adding (B*R) to each.
```

You will have overshot N by a few; if that's critical, then randomly select as many buckets as needed and remove one value from each.

Comment: My A3 seems to be the special case A=1 in your version. So it is like having A of my U/N intervals and allow the A random numbers to choose any of the A intervals. While this seems to allow more freedom intuitively, e.g. this includes the extreme case that A random numbers lie in one U/N interval, I wonder if this makes a difference in the end, as we (or at least I :-) expect some kind of uniform spread of the random numbers over the U range.

Answer (score -1):

10^12 is about 2^40, ie average step between sequential values will be 2^24.

Therefore, if goal is to generate unpredictable, but ordered hashes sequence, then it not possible, 2^24 is too easy for bruteforce

But if it not goal, then why not just join incremental 2^40 counter in top bits with 2^24 random value in lower bits?

Comment: I think you are guessing how I want to use that sequence. What is your guess? I need it for a simulation, one that should be as real-world as possible, not to protect against something. In your solution, (almost) exactly half the values would be below 0, which is not random.

Answer (score -2):

You want a lot of pseudo-random 64 bit numbers, all unique.  Given unique inputs and the same key, encryption is unique -- it has to be because it is reversible.  DES is a 64-bit block cipher, so encrypting the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...  10^12 in DES with ECB mode will give you a trillion unique 64-bit numbers.  With the same key they are guaranteed unique because the inputs are unique.  A different key will given a different set of unique numbers, but some may be duplicates of numbers in the first set.

For 128 bit numbers use AES, which has a 128 bit block size, again in ECB mode and with a fixed key.

The only internal state needed is the key you are using and a single number indicating how far you have got in the [0..10^12] range.

You will need to sort the output separately.  Given the ease of restarting the process from the stored last number to generate the next batch of numbers, I suspect that a merge-sort would be relatively easy to implement, with each new batch being merged into the already sorted main file as you produce it.  Batch sizes can be kept to within memory capacity, with the major file being held on disc.

This solution does not use `java.util.Random`.  How important is that for you?  Encryption is designed to appear random to all but the most sophisticated cryptographic analysis and is probably 'more random' than the standard Java `Random` PRNG.

Comment: Nice trick to use reversible encryption! The problem is sorting 10^12 entries. It will take days. This is 8 TB.

Comment: Use Radix Sort.  Make 256 files.  The first holds numbers starting 0x00... and the last holds numbers starting 0xFF...  sort the files separately in parallel.  The Radix Sort idea can be extended depending on the hardware available, maybe 4096 files: 0x000... to 0xFFF...?

Comment: Look, I specially asked for a solution _without_ disk I/O. Sorting 8 TB is simply too slow.